# using feature counts in sci-kit tf-idf

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Let's say I have a list of feature counts with n categories/labels, ex:

```
feature 1,label1 = 10 # word, label = frequency count
feature 1,label2 = 0
feature 2,label1 = 3
feature 2,label2 = 0
```

If it was json, it would be something like this for the words "bad" and "good":

```
{
 "bad": {"pos": 1, "neg": 15, "neu": 2},
 "good": {"pos": 13, "neg": 3, "neu": 2},
}
```

This is on file and was inherited from an old application (i don't have access to the original documents, long story) but they are relevant and i would like to use them. This application was  a sentiment classification app that would fetch newspaper comments and classify them, the same as the one i would like to develop.

So, how do i feed these counts to Tf-df Vectorizer or CountVectorizer *or* merge them with the results obtained from running the vectorizer, ie, with X_train_count from the code below:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> count_vect = CountVectorizer()
>>> data_train = {"data": ["ola good", "hey good", "good", "good", "bad", "bad", "bad"], "target":[1,1,1,1,0,0,0]}
>>> X_train_count = count_vect.fit_transform(data_train["data"])
>>> count_vect.get_feature_names()
[u'bad', u'good']
>>> print X_train_count
  (0, 1)        1
  (1, 1)        1
  (2, 1)        1
  (3, 1)        1
  (4, 0)        1
  (5, 0)        1
  (6, 0)        1
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The code snippet you give are not valid. Please fix them if you want us to be of some help. For instance `count_vect.get_feature_names()` cannot return anything before fit is called. Also I don't understand what you mean by: "word, label = frequency count". Are you trying to classify feature from a corpus of text documents? If so, where are the document boundaries?

Comment: Hi Ogrisel, i copy/pasted in the wrong order, it's fixed now. I also updated the question to clarify a bit more. Yes, i am trying to classify a document corpus and i have the features counts of an old application (it was using naive bayes and saving the updated feature counts in the database) - i would like to use these to classify the new corpus. What do you mean by document corpus? The list i have to train on is about 1500 samples, distributed between the positive, negative and neutral classes.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just have aggregated count for individual features and you no have the info of which feature occurred in which sample. You thus cannot use CountVectorizer to rebuild a full training dataset from only such partial aggregate info. It might be enough to build a naive bayes classifier though if you do the math and build it yourself. You won't be able to measure the perf though due to the lack of real test set.

Comment: Ok, thought that might be the case. Thanks